# JQuery undefined is not a function ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i use jquery for calculation in grid all done well instead that when it is grand total turn jquery throw an error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" at this line " $("[id*=txtTotal]").live("keyup", function () {", kindly give me suggestion.

---

Here is my code:

```
            function CalculateTotal(select) {

            var row = $(select).closest("tr");
            var ClPart = $("[id*=txtCl_Part]", row).val();
            //alert(ClPart.toString());
            var Assgnmnt = $("[id*=txtAssgnmnt]", row).val();
            //alert(Assgnmnt.toString());
            var Quiz = $("[id*=txtQuiz]", row).val();
            //alert(Quiz.toString());
            var WrPaper = $("[id*=txtWP]", row).val();
            //alert(WrPaper.toString());
            var OSME = $("[id*=txtOSME]", row).val();
            //alert(OSME.toString());
            var Total = (parseFloat(ClPart.valueOf()) + parseFloat(Assgnmnt.valueOf()) + parseFloat(Quiz.valueOf()) + parseFloat(WrPaper.valueOf()) + parseFloat(OSME.valueOf()));
            //   alert(Amount.toString());

            $("[id*=txtTotal]", row).val(Total.valueOf());
        }



        $("[id*=txtTotal]").live("keyup", function () {

           Error comes at above line


                var Gtot = 0;
                var percent = 0.0;
                $("[id*=txtTotal]").each(function (index) {
                    //Check if number is not empty
                    if ($.trim($(this).val()) != "")
                    //Check if number is a valid Float
                        if (!isNaN($(this).val()))
                            Gtot = Gtot + parseFloat($(this).val());
                    percent = (parseFloat(Gtot) * 100) / 400;
                });


                $("[id*=txtGTot]").val(Gtot.valueOf());
                $("[id*=txtPercent]").val(percent.valueOf());

            });
```

Comment: You may forgot to included JS librery. Kindly check!

Comment: I include jquery library like this
 <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

but i only inclde the above file. Is it enough or not?

Comment: And when you view your browser's debugging tools, does it show that it successfully loaded the jQuery library script?

Comment: Also, cross check the order of JS library included in your code and path. Thanks

Comment: yes mason, the code above that line is working fine but it stuck at that line

Comment: jeekonline it still not working

Comment: _When_ are you invoking that line. Has `jquery` loaded? Is DOM `ready`? It seems you're only declaring a `function` above that line so "working" isn't necessarily true...Hth

Comment: EdSF your right, debugger cant access to this code but my function is working...  what should I do in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Live was removed in jquery 1.9 per documentation (https://api.jquery.com/live/).

Instead, use the new "on" method

```
$("[id*=txtTotal]").on("keyup", function () {});
```

Comment: Thanks joel. it help me. the error i get is solved but this code is not running. can you help me on this?

Comment: it finally works...

Joel it will something like this

$(documnet).on("event","selector", function()
   {}
)

Answer (score 0):

//Let you handle an element even if it's not registered in DOM

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#<%=txtTotal.ClientID%>", function() {});
```

//Or do this

```
$("#<%=txtTotal.ClientID%>").keyup(function() {});
```

//Or this

```
$("#<%=txtTotal.ClientID%>").on("keyup",function() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

it finally works...

Joel it will something like this

$(documnet).on("event","selector", function()
   {}
)